# Получить доступ к переменной из класса наследника

Tags: java

Мне нужно записать переменную page из класса bumaga в массив All чтобы потом её вывести.Как это сделать с помощью get и set?

```
package booka;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Book {
    public String name;
    public String author;

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public Book(String name, String author) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Book:"+name+", "+author;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Name");
        String name = scan.next();

        System.out.println("Author");
        String author = scan.next();

        String page = scan.next();

        Book all = new Book(name, author); //массив
        Book[] array = { all };
        System.out.println(all);
    }
}
```

```
package booka;

public class bumaga extends Book {
    String page;

    public bumaga(String Name, String Author, String page) {
        super(Name, Author);
    }

    public String getPage() {
        return this.page;

    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. Сейчас ничего не понятно

Comment: в классе `Book` нет никакого массива

Comment: Как элемент книги может наследоваться от самой книиги?

Comment: @Tsyklop `Book all = new Book(name, author);`

Comment: @KrAsAw4iK и где тут масив? Вы содали объект класса Книга.

Comment: @Tsyklop   `Book all = new Book(name, author); 
        Book[] array = { all };
        System.out.println(all);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас какие-то проблемы с пониманием того, что вы делаете, отсюда и вопрос возник.
В вашей иерархии бумага - наследник книги. Суть наследования в том, что наследник обладает свойствами родителя, плюс дополняется своими свойствами.
Бумага же не обладает никакими свойствами книги (вот на свой код взгляните, у вас у бумаги получается есть имя и автор, у каждого листика, вроде довольно абсурдно, учитывая что вы её используете как страницу книги?). Соответственно наследовать бумагу от книги - неверно.

В вашем случае наследование можно применить разве что к бумаге и странице. Бумага - родитель, страница - наследник. Просто на бумаге может быть что угодно написано или нарисовано, а на странице должен быть упорядоченный текст, номер страницы например.

А класс книги внутри себя должен содержать массив страниц.

Ну и, собственно, отвечая на вопрос из заголовка: "Получить доступ к переменной из класса наследника", я так понимаю получить доступ к переменной наследника из класса-родителя? Это прямо противоречит принципу наследования, родитель ничего не должен знать о полях своих наследников.

**UPD.** ответ на вопрос из комментария:

```
Book[] books = new Book[2];
books[0] = new EBook();
books[1] = new PaperBook();
```

Comment: А можно ли записать в массив объекты из класса  наследника ?
Например у меня есть класс книга и  2 наследника бумажные книги и электронные и записать классы наследники в массив и в вывести

Comment: @KrAsAw4iK, да, конечно можно, обновил ответ, привер пример